# Kafka compaction logic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to understand how compaction works. For example, I have topic with 2 partitions, with configs TopicConfig.SEGMENT_BYTES_CONFIG, "200" and TopicConfig.MIN_CLEANABLE_DIRTY_RATIO_CONFIG, "0.01". I send to topic next messages(with a small delay between sending):

```
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "A",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "A",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "B",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "D",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "A",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "D",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "B",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "A",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "B",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "B",
        country));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test-v1", "E",
        country));
```

and expect to have 4 messages with keys "A", "B", "D", "E". but this map contains offsets 3 and 8

```
Map<TopicPartition, Long> partitionLastOffsetMap = consumer.endOffsets(partitions);
```

consumer reads 9 messages. why? can anyone explain the logic? thanks in advance

Comment: As mentioned before, Kafka doesn't compact immediately, and it is not advised to configure it to do so. If you expect unique keys, then create/use a KTable... Also, latest Kafka includes transaction markers, by default, so there will be some "empty offsets", therefore counting them / looking at the end wont be very useful